# Format DataFrame to row-oriented JSON object (spreadsheet-style pivot table)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've a pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex levels that looks like the following:

[image]

And now I'm trying to convert this dataframe into a row-oriented JSON object (or [spreadsheet-style pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)?), where the result should look like the following:

```
[{"date":"2016-11-08T23:00:00.000Z", "flag":0, "value":545.0, "moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B", "locationId":"location_1" },  
 {"date":"2016-11-09T23:00:00.000Z", "flag":0, "value":545.0, "moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B", "locationId":"location_1" },
 {"date":"2016-11-10T23:00:00.000Z", "flag":8, "value":-999.0, "moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B", "locationId":"location_1" },
 {"date":"2016-11-11T23:00:00.000Z", "flag":0, "value":680.0, "moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B", "locationId":"location_1" },
 {"date":"2016-11-12T23:00:00.000Z", "flag":8, "value":-999.0, "moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B", "locationId":"location_1" }]
```

I tried to use the following command

```
df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

but then the MultiIndex structure stays intact.

The above used dummy set can be created as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

input_dict = {('module_A',
  'parameter_B',
  'location_1',
  'flag'): {  Timestamp('2016-11-09 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-10 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-11 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 8,
  Timestamp('2016-11-12 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-13 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 8},
 ('module_A',
  'parameter_B',
  'location_1',
  'value'): {  Timestamp('2016-11-09 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 545.0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-10 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 545.0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-11 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): -999.0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-12 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): 680.0,
  Timestamp('2016-11-13 05:30:00+0630', tz='Asia/Yangon'): -999.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(input_dict)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) first:

```
df = df.stack([0,1,2]).rename_axis(['date','moduleId','parameterId','locationId'])
d = df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

```
print (d)

[{"date":"2016-11-08T23:00:00.000Z","moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B","locationId":"location_1","flag":0,"value":545.0},
 {"date":"2016-11-09T23:00:00.000Z","moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B","locationId":"location_1","flag":0,"value":545.0},
 {"date":"2016-11-10T23:00:00.000Z","moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B","locationId":"location_1","flag":8,"value":-999.0},
 {"date":"2016-11-11T23:00:00.000Z","moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B","locationId":"location_1","flag":0,"value":680.0},
 {"date":"2016-11-12T23:00:00.000Z","moduleId":"module_A","parameterId":"parameter_B","locationId":"location_1","flag":8,"value":-999.0}]
```

Comment: Wow! That's even less code then I expected. Can even be an one-liner. This is great